# Assembler 64 bit mutiple definition error

Tags: c, assembly, compilation

I am trying to learn Assembly, and using it with 64 bit. I want to compile an inline Assembler in C, but I get an error every time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

__asm__ ( "mov %rdx, 10;"
          "mov %rcx, 20;"
          "add %rdx, rcx;"
);


__asm__ ( "mov %rdx, 10;"
          "mov %rcx, 20;"
          "sub %rcx, %rdx;"
);

__asm__ ( "mov %rdx, 10;"
          "mov %rcx, 20;"
          "sub %rcx, %rdx;"
);


__asm__ ( "mov %rdx, 10;"
          "mov %rcx, 20;"
          "imul %rdx, %rcx;"
);

return 0 ;
}
```

If I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
gcc -o onetest onetest.o onetest.c

/tmp/ccXkj6UQ.o: In function `main':

onetest.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'

onetest.o:onetest.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here

/tmp/ccXkj6UQ.o: In function `main':

one.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `rcx'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At the beginning I had a few problems with registers, but now this too!

Comment: `gcc -o onetest onetest.o onetest.c` <-- that doesn't look right. Try `gcc -o onetest onetest.c`

Comment: Also, your first assembler block has `rcx` instead of `%rcx` in the `add` instruction.

Comment: If you use % prefix like AT&T syntax then you cannot move something to a constant. The correct syntax should be `mov $10, %rdx`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with assembler, but a linker.

```
gcc -o onetest onetest.o onetest.c
```

Tries to compile & link `onetest.o` and `onetest.c` together, where I assume `onetest.o` is derived from `onetest.c`. You are compiling that thing twice. Try

```
gcc -o onetest onetest.c
```

**Edit:**

If you want to actually have your asm interact with your C code then you are best off with extended asm. Example:

```
int64_t result = 10; // one of the arguments
asm (
    "add %1, %0"
    : "+r" (result) // input-output variable
    : "g" (20)      // second argument
    : "cc"
    );

printf("result = %lld\n", result);
```

Please keep in mind that in AT&T x86 syntax `add, %a, %b` works as `%b += %a`.

For the extended asm constrains: `"+r"` instructs your compiler to provide `result` in a register of it's choosing (available as `%0` in the asm) for input and output. `"g"` instructs your compiler to provide `20` in any form it finds suitable for input only (available as `%1` in asm). `"cc"` signals your compiler that the conditions flags register `EFLAGS` in x86 will be altered by your asm (a side effect of `add`).

Comment: I have now a .c .o .s file

Comment: @user3616107 What exactly do you want to get? Please specify in your question.

Comment: I would like to get a result after all operations

Comment: @user3616107 What result? What shall it contain? In what form? What is the program supposed to do?

Comment: Alternative, use two commands: `gcc -c onetest.c` to produce *onetest.o* object file, then `gcc -o onetest onetest.o` to produce *onetest* executable.

Comment: @Wlad So you want *program exit code* to be the sum, in other words you want to return asm register value from `main()` function? Or do you actually want to *print* it?

Comment: @Wlad Added an example of how to interact with the `asm`.

Comment: @hyde so could you tell my why I get this error Assembler messages: Error: too many memory references for `mov'

Comment: I remove the % symbole

Comment: @SergeyL. I mean 10+20 and return 30